# executionContext vs primaryControl

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am having issues using the same code in two scenarios:

1. From a ribbon button call **revisionRequested** which in turn calls **removeOptions** and
2. from the form OnLoad, call **removeOptions** only.

The code below is my work around, but I what I originally tried was to pass the `primaryControl` param from `revisionRequested` to `removeOptions` in which I made **formContext = primaryControl** I got an error.

```
    function revisionRequested(primaryControl) {
    
        var formContext = primaryControl;
        formContext.getAttribute("statuscode").setValue(100000009);  // Revision Requested
        removeOptions(0, primaryControl);
    
        Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog('Your revision request has been been submitted');
    }
    
    function removeOptions(executionContext, primaryControl) {
        var formContext = null;
        executionContext == 0 ? formContext = primaryControl : formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    
        var statusCode = formContext.getAttribute("statuscode").getText();
        var statusControl = formContext.getControl("header_statuscode");
    
        if (Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() !== 1 && statusCode.includes('Revision')) {
            statusControl.removeOption(1);
            statusControl.removeOption(100000000);
            statusControl.removeOption(100000001);
            statusControl.removeOption(100000002);
            statusControl.removeOption(100000003);
            statusControl.removeOption(100000003);
            statusControl.removeOption(100000004);
            statusControl.removeOption(100000005);
            statusControl.removeOption(100000006);
            statusControl.removeOption(100000007);
            statusControl.removeOption(100000008);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the question, it is little unclear.

Comment: When I pass the primaryControl initially to removeOptions it did not behave the same as when the executionContext was passed from the form OnLoad.  Why is that?

Comment: Any followup questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want is polymorphism in JavaScript for `removeOptions` method, one with `executionContext` signature to use from form load, another one with `primaryControl` signature to use from ribbon. These two signatures are not same of course, and passing execution context from the form while registering event handlers have only choice to send it as first parameter.

What you did is valid workaround to utilize the reusable method in two different places with all limitations and platform design into consideration.

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48202316) discussion for more understanding.